# How to make a hierarchical Json in java

Tags: java, json

I have a requirement to make a json structure like a tree node where some root nodes will be there and they have some children. My json structure is like this what I am posting ..

```
{
chart: {
    caption: "Subscriber Summary Percentage",
    xAxisName: "Month",
    yAxisName: "% Subscriber",
    showvalues: "0",
    palette: "1"
},
categories: [
    {
        category: [
            {
                label: "JAN"
            },
            {
                label: "FEB"
            },
            {
                label: "MAR"
            },
            {
                label: "APR"
            },
            {
                label: "MAY"
            },
            {
                label: "JUN"
            },
            {
                label: "JUL"
            },
            {
                label: "AUG"
            },
            {
                label: "SEP"
            }
        ]
    }
],
dataset: [
    {
        seriesname: "New Added",
        data: [
            {
                value: "1.1887604"
            },
            {
                value: "2.1255539"
            },
            {
                value: "2.3852911"
            },
            {
                value: "2.9953901000000003"
            },
            {
                value: "2.5770609"
            },
            {
                value: "2.8420104000000004"
            },
            {
                value: "4.543343"
            },
            {
                value: "3.7596994"
            },
            {
                value: "5.0751309000000004"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        seriesname: "Churned",
        data: [
            {
                value: "2.4009264"
            },
            {
                value: "2.4021593"
            },
            {
                value: "2.8101032000000004"
            },
            {
                value: "3.1267909000000005"
            },
            {
                value: "3.790831"
            },
            {
                value: "3.9487281"
            },
            {
                value: "4.533631"
            },
            {
                value: "5.0275186"
            },
            {
                value: "5.4198564"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

this is my json structure can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using a JSON library?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an API to manage your JSON, there are several available for Java which are reliable and fast. Pick one mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library and then it will do the heavy lifting for you. Its too easy to make mistakes if you're manipulating the text yourself.

Following sample using Jackson library (download the library from http://jackson.codehaus.org/) but similar concepts applicable to most other JSON libraries.

Your JSON is pretty straightforward. Create a Java POJO for each unique type (anything that isn't a primitive like `int` or `String`) and then annotate them with `@JsonProperty` and `@XmlRootElement(name="")` or whatever your API uses.

```
public class Chart{

  @JsonProperty
  public String caption;
  @JsonProperty
  public String xAxisName;
  @JsonProperty
  public String yAxisName;
  @JsonProperty
  public boolean showValues;
  @JsonProperty
  public int palette;
}

public class Categories{
   @JsonProperty
   public String[] category;//or whatever data type you're using, a tuple or something, category class array if you like
}
```

etc.

And then ultimately

```
public class CategoryJSON{
@JsonProperty
public Chart chart;
@JsonProperty
public Categories category;

}
```

Then your API should know how to automatically serialize and deserialize JSON of that format, just pass the class type. Here's Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
CategoryJSON c = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, CategoryJSON.class);  //read
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(c)); //write
```

Comment: For reference this is using the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) JSON library - there are several other libraries you could use instead.

Comment: @IanRoberts edited to be more clear that this was Jackson and you'll need to use the appropriate annotations.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that will be highly dependent on the JSON framework being used, which the person asking the question didn't specify. You shouldn't be rolling your own JSON solution.

Comment: You probably should move that comment "You shouldn't be rolling your own JSON solution." into the answer. Assuming OP does not know any library suggesting one particular with concrete sample sound like a good answer to me (I don't know Java myself - would edit otherwise).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov done deal. :)

Comment: +1. I've reordered paragraphs to highlight "don't reinvent wheel".